# 2 div, one most left, one most right, when resizing window, need second div jump to next line but appear on the most left

Tags: css, html

I want to have the following effect

2 divs, one on the left side of the screen, one on the right side of the screen, but when I resize the screen, when the same line is not big enough for both div, I want the second div jump to the next line, but it should appear on the most left side of the window instead, is this even possible?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried so far? Hint in the right direction: Look into "media queries"

Answer (score 2):

For example let the divs be 200px width and height;

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

.container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .container div {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;

    }

.left { float: left;  background-color: blue; }
.right { float: right; background-color: green; }

/* The magic part */
@media (max-width: 399px) {
    .right {
        float: left;   
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5m8Lj/

Take a look on CSS media queries like @reinder suggested